# ASP.NET MVC with edmx and ViewModel - Exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel, edmx

I have an edmx model generated from the database but I use the ViewModel to create modified columns and display it in my `table` elements in `View` (using the LINQ shown in `UserController`). I think this might have a connection to the error I'm getting when I'm using connection #2. But I think using connection #1 would be better for me because I now use ViewModels in displaying database records in View instead of directly getting it from the `DBEntites`.

I. If I use connection #1, I'm encountering error when navigating to `Create` view of `UserController` in runtime. The error shows up in `DBModel.Context` and `UserController` (see codes and error below).

Web.config

```
//Connection #1
<add name="DBEntities" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=user;Password=pass;Data Source=DBDEV" />
//Connection #2
<!--<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=DBDEV;PASSWORD=pass;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
```

DBModel.Context.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DBModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException'
>   occurred in DB.dll but was not handled in user code

UserController.cs

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    DBEntities _db = new DBEntities(); 

    public ActionResult Create(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        //Having error with the code below:
        var users = from u in _db.USR_MSTR
                         select new UserViewModel
                         {
                             userId = u.USR_ID,
                             userDesc = u.USR_DESC,
                             userStatus = (u.INACTV_DT == null ? "Active" : "Inactive")
                         };
        return View(users.ToList());
    }
}
```

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

This error shows as an additional error in both 2 exceptions shown above:

> Additional information: The context is being used in Code First mode
>   with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database
>   First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To
>   fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this
>   exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make
>   sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the
>   app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating
>   your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection
>   and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one
>   of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn
>   more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
>   Framework documentation here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

UserViewModel.cs

```
namespace DB.Models
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public string userDesc { get; set; }
        public string userStatus { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

II. If I use connection #2, unlike using connection #1, I will be able to view my table element with records from database when navigating to `Create` view of `UserController` in runtime. I have a button in my `View` that has onclick pointing to my `Javascript` with `AJAX` calling the `JsonResult` in `UserController`. However, I can't add to the database when I press the submit button because it generates an error in this line:

`using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBEntities"].ConnectionString))`

Save_User function in UserController.cs

```
public JsonResult Save_User(UserViewModel model)
{
    using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBEntities"].ConnectionString))
    {
        USR_MSTR P_Table = new USR_MSTR();
        string tbl_name = Convert.ToString(P_Table);
        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(20);

        string p_paramval = String.Format(id + "," + model.userDesc + "," + null + "," + null + "," + null);
        string p_table_nameval = tbl_name.Replace("CDS.", "");

        var cmd = new OracleCommand("sp_insert", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_param", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = p_paramval;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_table_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = p_table_nameval;
        try
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ViewBag.message = "Successfully Saved";

            return Json(true);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Close();
        }
    }
```

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'metadata' is an invalid connection string
>   attribute

Comment: To sum it all up: Using connection #1, I can't even go to my View as it already generates an error. Using connection #2, I can access my View and see the records from database but when I click Submit button to save a record, it generates an error in the `Oracle Connection`. I want to know what makes the error show up and what should I do to fix it. Thanks guys!